# Define a new sub-folder naming - Multisite

Tags: multisite, routing

Does anybody know how to redefine the naming of subfolders in WP Multisite during a new website creation? I want the next URI

```
www.wp.mu/sub1/sub2/
```

So, the new website in the network will be under the URI **/sub1/sub2/**. Another one could be under **/sub1/sub3/** or **/sub4/sub2/**. What I have stumbled on is the restriction to add the slash in the subfolder name.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that a lot of people will not know what you mean by WPMU, are you sure you don't mean a Multisite install?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @tom-j-nowell . I've edited the title and the body.